# How to merge a DataFrame for both column-wise and row wise into 1D array?

Tags: python, pandas

Guys,

I have a DataFrame read from csv, it looks like as following (use simple number and X to simplify) :

```
X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,X
X,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,X
X,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,X
X,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,X
X,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,X
```

Here it is my needs - I want to generate a 1D array/list from the DataFrame above with :

1. I need to remove all X values (which is only happened in first row, first column, and last column)
2. Create a column wise array - 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,...,8,8,8,8
3. Create a row wise array - 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...

I want to know the simplest code for those purpose, really appreciate.

Regards,
Wangyang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1 : `iloc`

```
df.iloc[1:, 1:-1]

   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
3  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
4  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

---

#### 2 : `unstack`

For column-wise

```
df.iloc[1:, 1:-1].unstack()
```

---

#### 3: `stack`

For row-wise

```
df.iloc[1:, 1:-1].stack()
```

## ____________________________________________

A Numpy take

```
a = np.array([center for left, *center, right in zip(*map(df.get, df))][1:], dtype=int)
a

array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Column-wise

```
np.ravel(a, order='F')

[1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8]
```

Row-wise

```
np.ravel(a)
# np.ravel(a, order='C')

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your row-wise array use,

```
df.iloc[1:,1:-1].stack().values
```

For your column-wise array use,

```
df.iloc[1:,1:-1].unstack().values
```